# Are most home circuits able to handle 12V 50 amps on a 10/20/50 Amps?

Tags: battery-charging, home-installation

My dad is saying that most home outlets can't handle 12V 50 Amps, is this true, or false? What I'm doing it for is to charge my car battery.

Comment: Do you mean can an outlet power a 12v, 50A battery charger?  If so, yes, that is only 600w.

Comment: home outlets are not 12 V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no problem for the wall outlet to supply 120VAC (5 amps, plus losses, plus a bit for "12V" battery chargers run above 12 volts in real life, but still less than half a 15 amp outlet's capacity) to run the charger at 12VDC/50A

It's usually a bad idea to use the 50A setting on the charger for the sake of the **battery**, not the wall outlet.

On the third hand, if you need to use a battery charger on your car much at all, either the battery is well on its way to expiring or you need to fix the charging system in the car. But you can certainly hasten the demise of a battery on its way out by smacking it with a 50A charge.

Comment: 50A may be too much for the contacts on a standard wall ou 1tlet, it may overheat. You may want to dig into the ratings. 50A*20mOhm is 1 watt in a small area, if the contacts were worse, it could be 5W or more

Comment: The question is poorly written, but is asking about running a 12VDC battery charger at 50A. The wall outlet would be well within ratings, running possibly 6.5 A at 120VAC if the charger is not very efficient.